Ubuntu 24.04 and AMD Radeon HD 7770 Video Card
I've been trying to get new installations of Ubuntu 24.04 and Ubuntu Studio 24.04 to connect to a modern display, an HP OMEN 32c.The computer I am trying to repurpose has an early I-7, 16 GB memory, and an AMD Radeon HD 7770 video card. To get them installed I had to use an old HP 2311 monitor. In Ubuntu studio I could connect the OMEN as a second monitor but could not get the OMEN display connected by itself. Ubuntu will not connect to the OMEN display at all. I was able to use the OMEN display during the initial boot menu and UEFI adjustments to point to booting up from the USB. Installation  script would not hook up to the OMEN, only the old HP display. Firefox searches and Ask Ubuntu searches show that others are having similar troubles with Radeon video cards. Is there any chance of finding a solution or should I give up and possibly try a different distribution? OpenSUSE and Fedora had similar problems. Is there any way to test the Radeon from a USB boot up?
